# Contracts cannot be satisfied by an AutomaticPlaceholderConstraint placeholder

Tags: java, transactions, corda, contract

My Corda application consists of one `Contract`, two `OwnableStates` the Initiator `FlowLogic` and the Responder `FlowLogic`.  The transaction I am trying to form has two inputs and two outputs. One input is supposed to be an asset and the other one a currency for which I created an own `OwnableState`.

I added the inputs and outputs like this to the transaction builder:

```
TransactionBuilder txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);
        txBuilder.addInputState(new StateAndRef<AssetState>(new TransactionState<AssetState>(inputAsset, notary), new StateRef(SecureHash.sha256("com.template.contracts.Contract"), 0)));
        txBuilder.addInputState(new StateAndRef<CurrencyState>(new TransactionState<CurrencyState>(inputCurrency, notary), new StateRef(SecureHash.sha256("com.template.contracts.ContractCurrency"), 1)));
        txBuilder.addOutputState(outputAsset, notary);
        txBuilder.addOutputState(outputCurrency, notary);
        txBuilder.addCommand(command);
```

The only difference between the input and output states are the owners. Both the currency and the asset state belong to one contract. The verifying logic of this contract is shown below:

```
 @Override    
    public void verify(LedgerTransaction tx) {

        List<InOutGroup<AssetState, AssetState>> AssetGroups = tx.groupStates(AssetState.class, AssetState::withoutOwner);
        List<InOutGroup<CurrencyState, CurrencyState>> CurrencyGroups = tx.groupStates(CurrencyState.class, CurrencyState::withoutOwner);
        CommandWithParties<Commands> cmd = requireSingleCommand(tx.getCommands(), Commands.class);

        for (InOutGroup AssetGroup : AssetGroups) {
            List<AssetState> AssetInputs = AssetGroup.getInputs();
            List<AssetState> AssetOutputs = AssetGroup.getOutputs();

            AssetState AssetInput = AssetsInputs.get(0);
            if (cmd.getValue() instanceof Commands.Transfer) {
                requireThat(require -> {
                        require.using("the transaction is signed by the owner of the Asset", cmd.getSigners().contains(AssetInput.getOwner().getOwningKey()));
                        return null;
                }); 
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised command");
            } 

            for (InOutGroup CurrencyGroup : CurrencyGroups) {
                List<CurrencyState> CurrencyInputs = CurrencyGroup.getInputs();
                List<CurrencyState> CurrencyOutputs = CurrencyGroup.getOutputs();

                if (cmd.getValue() instanceof Commands.Transfer) {
                    CurrencyState CurrencyInput = CurrencyInputs.get(0);
                    requireThat(require -> {
                        require.using("the transaction is signed by the owner of the Currency", cmd.getSigners().contains(CurrencyInput.getOwner().getOwningKey()));
                        return null;
                    }); 
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised command");
            }
        }
    }}
```

When executing the `TransactionFlow` in the terminal I receive the error:

```
Contracts cannot be satisfied by an AutomaticPlaceholderConstraint placeholder.
```

I couldn't find anything online that helps me and I am not sure where to look for the error. Therefore, I would appreciate your help. Thanks!

Disclaimer: I changed the names of classes and variables to make it easier to understand. If there is a typo in the names please ignore it. I am sure that this is not the issue ;).

Comment: are both of your states connected to the same Contract class? It is done through the tag: `@BelongsToContract(<CONTRACT>::class)
`

Answer (score 0):

We have three types of Constraints - **HashConstraint, WhiteListListedByZone, Signature**. When we create the input state for the first time, it gets associated with one of the constraint. When you create a transaction by adding input and output states to it, and if you haven't explicitly specified which constraint to use for the output state, the input state constraint is propagated to the output state. In such a scenario, AutomaticPlaceholderConstraint is used by default when you create a transaction, as you haven't explicitly specified the constraint. Which output constraint to use is evaluated and assigned to the output state. Sometimes, it is not able to evaluate the correct output state constraint and this is when it throws an exception. I think this is what is happening with your case. Could you paste additional logs which could help me understand more.

Some situations which won't work eg -
Input states using HashConstraint or WhiteListByZoneConstraint, output states trying to use Signature constraint

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are building your transaction is probably the problem. The input to the transaction should be the state available currently in the ledger.

Considering the below piece of code to add the input state to the transaction:

`txBuilder.addInputState(new StateAndRef<AssetState>(new TransactionState<AssetState>(inputAsset, notary), new StateRef(SecureHash.sha256("com.template.contracts.Contract"), 0)));`

The `addInputState` method accepts a `StateAndRef` object, the state part is fine but the ref is a reference to the transaction which produced the state, so the 2nd parameter to the method which is the `StateRef` should contain the `trnxId` and the `output_index`. In your case, the `SecureHash` is not the `trnxId`, but the sha256 hash of the string "com.template.contracts.Contract".

A easier way to add the input to the transaction is the feed the result of the vaultQuery directly. The vaultQuery returns a StateAndRef obeject which can be passed as a parameter to the addInputState method. For example:

```
getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(SampleState.class)
    .getStates().stream()
    // Filter based on field value "XYZ"
    .filter(sampleStateAndRef -> {
        SampleState sampleState = sampleStateStateAndRef.getState().getData();
                return sampleState.getField().equals("XYZ");
        }).findAny().orElseThrow(() -> new FlowException("State Not Found"));
```

Hope this helps!